# iOS - UINavigationController and adding a left bar button?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

The following mwthod is the delegate method of a UINavigationController. I want to be abel to decide whether to add the left item to each page or not. The code below doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

**I don't want to perform this through the ViewController itself. I want the NavigationCopntroller to be responsible for this task.**

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *menuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize 
                                                                                  target:self 
                                                                                  action:@selector(menuItemSelected:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:menuItem];

    // I also tried 
    // [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:menuItem];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a warning in console saying that "Nested Push could corrupt the navigationController"
I was pushing 2 Viewcontroller into the stack, instead of pushing 1 viewController at a time.

Fixing this problem and getting rid of the warning fixed this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you're trying to acces the `navigationItem` property on the viewController but it doesn't exist because in the `willShowViewController` method the viewController is not in the navigationController stack yet, try using the `didShowViewController` delegate method

Like this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIBarButtonItem *menuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize 
                                                                                  target:self 
                                                                                  action:@selector(menuItemSelected:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:menuItem];

    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:menuItem];
```

}